# Apache PHP connections

Tags: apache-2.2, php, connection

I installed a site on a new Ubuntu server. When I'm downloading something from that site, the server doesn't accept additional connections from that user.

If I click on one link it doesn't respond until the download finishes.

Any idea why this happens in Apache, what in the configuration should I change?

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: Can you provide more information? What are you downloading with? Are there any errors in apache logfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP1.1 standard limits client connections to web servers to 2 concurrent connections.  This is a client limitation, not a server limitation and you can increase it.

[Changing limit in IE5.5+](http://www.dewassoc.com/support/useful/registry/ie_connect_limit.htm)

[Changing limit in Firefox](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-tweak-firefoxs-maximum-connection-limit/)

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly more related to the client, rather than the server

What application are you downloading with?

If memory serves, Firefox (for instance) defaults to a small number of connections to the same server. Apache, I don't think, doesn't limit the number of connections from a client by default